# Ruby travel time

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to calculate a random travel time until it passes 1000 miles. So far, I can't figure out why it doesn't output the results, it just stays with the user input. Help please

```
def travel_time()
    printf "Pick a vehicle: \n"
    printf "1.  Bicycle \n"
    printf "2.  Car \n"
    printf "3.  Jet Plane \n"
    puts "Choose 1-3: \n"
    vehicle = gets.chomp

  case vehicle
    when "1"
        #Bicycle: 5-15 miles per hour
        time = 0
        distance = 0
        until distance > 1000 do
         speed = Random.rand(5...15)
         distance = speed * 1
         time = time + 1
        end
        puts "The number of hours it took to travel 1000 miles was #{time} hours"
    when "2"
        #Car: 20-70 miles per hour
        time = 0
        distance = 0
        until distance > 1000 do
        speed = Random.rand(20...70)
        distance = speed * 1
        time = time + 1
        end
        puts "The number of hours it took to travel 1000 miles was #{time} hours"

    when "3"
        #Jet Plane: 400-600 miles per hour
        time = 0
        distance = 0
        until distance > 1000 do
        speed = Random.rand(400...600)
        distance = speed * 1
        time = time + 1
        end
        puts "The number of hours it took to travel 1000 miles was #{time} hours"
    end
end
travel_time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
until distance > 1000 do
  speed = Random.rand(5...15)
  distance = speed * 1
  time = time + 1
end
```

This loop will never ende because the biggest value `distance` can get is `15`, so i think you want to add to `distance`, not replace it; son try using `+=` instead of `=`:

```
until distance > 1000 do
  speed = Random.rand(5...15)
  distance += speed * 1
  time = time + 1
end
```

Same goes for all loops in each case.

> How can I save the maximum speed and return it in a statement like I
>   have done?

One way to do it would be to add another variable (i.e. `max_speed`) and assign `speed` value to it whenever `speed` is greater than `max_speed`:

```
time = 0
distance = 0
max_speed = 0

until distance > 1000 do
  speed = Random.rand(5...15)
  max_speed = speed if speed > max_speed
  distance += speed * 1
  time = time + 1
end

puts "The maximum speed was #{max_speed} miles per hour"
```

Another way would be to use an array (although i prefer the first option):

```
speed = []

until distance > 1000 do
  speed << Random.rand(5...15)
  distance += speed.last * 1
  time = time + 1
end

puts "The maximum speed was #{speed.max} miles per hour"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was such an easy fix, but I have another question How can I save the maximun speed and return it in a statement like I have done?

Comment: @Renato Check the updated answer, i included an example.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I was trying to do it with arrays and coulnd't get anything save into the array

Comment: @Renato You could use an array if you like; check the updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually summing up the distance -  distance is never going to increase past 1000

```
until distance > 1000 do
  speed = Random.rand(5...15)
  distance = speed * 1 # will never equal more than 15
  time = time + 1
end
```

You probably want

```
distance += speed * 1 # not sure why you're multiplying by 1 though
```

Answer (score 0):

As a style comment: don't use `case` statements as control flow like if/then statements. Just use them to set values, and move everything else out. This can eliminate a lot of redundant code. Example:

```
time = 0
distance = 0
until distance > 1000 do   
  speed = case vehicle
    when "1" then Random.rand(5...15)    #Bicycle
    when "2" then Random.rand(20...70)   #Car
    when "3" then Random.rand(400...600) #Plane
    end
  distance += speed * 1
  time = time + 1
end
puts "The number of hours it took to travel 1000 miles was #{time} hours"
```